# Convert unusual string format to Datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, type-conversion

I receive dates in this format: `Wed Jun 29 2016 15:57:45 GMT 0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

What is the best way to either convert that string to `datetime` as-is, or cut it down enough to be converted (e.g. `Jun 29 2016 15:57:45`) without the risk of losing data?

Comment: Best way to store a datetime string is in `Datetime` datatype. Never store it as string it will be real pain while parsing

Comment: Yes, I want to convert it to `Datetime`.

Comment: CLR regex-based conversion function.

Comment: Is everything GMT 0100 or are different time zones represented? if different zones I would not want to loose that part during conversion and would either use a DATETIMEOFFSET or Convert to DATETIMEOFFSET then to a local time as DATETIME......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Substring` and `Charindex` string functions to trim the datetime

Try this

```
declare @date_str varchar(100) = 'Wed Jun 29 2016 15:57:45 GMT 0100 (GMT Daylight Time)'

select cast(substring(@date_str,charindex(' ',@date_str),charindex('GMT',@date_str)-charindex(' ',@date_str)) as datetime)
```

**Result :** `2016-06-29 15:57:45.000`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this. It searches for the location of the string 'GMT' in the `charindex`. It then uses the `substring` to split the value out (ignoring the first 4 characters) and converts the result to `datetime`.

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (OriginalValue nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO #TestData (OriginalValue)
VALUEs ('Wed Jun 29 2016 15:57:45 GMT 0100 (GMT Daylight Time)')
```

Query

```
SELECT 
OriginalValue
,CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING(OriginalValue,4,CHARINDEX('GMT',OriginalValue)-5)) NewValue
FROM #TestData
```

Result

```
OriginalValue                                           NewValue
Wed Jun 29 2016 15:57:45 GMT 0100 (GMT Daylight Time)   2016-06-29 15:57:45.000
```

Comment: May go for a toss when day name is more than 3 characters

Comment: Except Wednesday has more than three characters. Seems that the OP is using three character values for his day names.

Comment: 3 characters is always used. But it's not me choosing this insane date format, I'm just stuck with it.

Comment: Only 3 characters so what is Thursday abbreviated as for my own curiosity?

Comment: Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun

Comment: @Matt - why is it interesting, it seems logical that if three characters are used that Thursday would be in fact Thu.  It isn't rocket science pal.  How do I downvote comments again?  This is a prime candidate.

Comment: OP has already confirmed that three characters are used for day name, does it matter which three letters are used? Also, that naming convention is the only one that I have ever seen used anywhere, why would it be anything else? Lastly, you can tag whomever you are asking the question to by using @Matt

Comment: I asked the question because many times data is not thoroughly investigated when first asked, e.g. no one thought  about or mentioned whether different time zones are represented instead of all 0100 GMT that is in the example. Thursday is a good example of day that is abbreviated with 4 characters if not constrained to 3.  It is my practice to allow OP to answer questions in regards to his/her data or to suggest that one potential answer could be....  Interestingly if day of week is always 3 characters then month probably is too and if so you can write with no charindex's at all......

Comment: As long as the date of the month is always 2 characters, what if it's before the 10th of the month? It's also my practice that if a question is asked in the comments of my answer and not directed towards anybody in particular that it's perfectly acceptable for me to answer that.

Comment: more good questions but likely MM 09 and DD 09 would be used if we are making assumptions

Comment: So you have issue with me making assumptions but it's ok when you make them? Shall we assume that OP is a grown up and can state if he has any unusual issues with his data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @w VARCHAR(MAX)= 'Wed Jun 29 2016 15:57:45 GMT 0100 (GMT Daylight Time)'

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@w, 4, (PATINDEX('%GMT%', @w)-4)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is a fixed length, and the pieces to the right and left that you are trying to get rid of don't grow or shrink, you should be to just do this.

```
DECLARE @DateStr VARCHAR(100)
SET @DateStr = 'Wed Jun 29 2016 15:57:45 GMT 0100 (GMT Daylight Time)'

SELECT CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(@DateStr,49),20) AS DATETIME)
```